# How to intercept the TAB key press to prevent standard focus change in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, focus

Normally when pressing the TAB key you change the focus to the next control in the given tab order. I would like to prevent that and have the TAB key do something else. In my case I'd like to change focus from a combobox to a completely different control. I can't do this by setting the tab order. I need to do this programatically. Any idea how? It seems like the KeyDown and KeyPress events can't handle TAB key correctly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Override `ProcessDialogKey` or `ProcessTabKey` on your Form and do the logic you want depending on which control is focused.

Answer (score 6):

Based on JRS's suggestion of using the PreviewKeyDown event, this sends the key press through to the control:

```
private void textBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
        e.IsInputKey = true;
}
```

Then you can handle the control's KeyDown event if you want to customise the behaviour:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The tab key was pressed while holding these modifier keys: "
                + e.Modifiers.ToString());
    }
}
```

---

## TextBoxBase alternative

If the control is derived from `TextBoxBase` (i.e. `TextBox` or `RichTextBox`), with the `Multiline` property set to `true`, then you can simply set the `AcceptsTab` property to `true`.

[TextBoxBase.AcceptsTab Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.acceptstab.aspx)

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether pressing the TAB key in a multiline text box control types a TAB character in the control instead of moving the focus to the next control in the tab order.

Comment: I was going to add `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;` to the example, but weirdly the `MessageBox` seems to prevent it from working (which is an entirely separate issue).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code on your `KeyDown` event:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) {
  //your logic
  e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

If the button clicked is Tab, then do any custom logic you want, then call `SuppressKeyPress` to stop the `KeyPress` event from firing and invoking the normal Tab logic for you.

Comment: e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

Comment: At least for Telerik controls the KeyDown event is not fired when Tab is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Override the control's LostFocus event see link below for examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since I am building a UserControl, I ended up using the `PreviewKeyDown` event on the control.  This avoids having to handle key press events on the host form.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown.aspx