# c# disable arrow navigation with tabcontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, tabcontrol, onkeyup

I have a tabcontrol in my form, and I need to use the keyup event to manage somethings.

When I press left or right button, the tab page change, and I wish to disable the tabcontrol keyboard navigation.

it's possible to do this?

Comment: Have you considered inheriting the control and then giving it your own functionality?

Comment: Can you handle these `somethings` at the `Form` level?

Comment: I manage the 'somethings' at form level, I use keyup of the form, but when I press left or right, the tab change the page

Comment: It isn't very clear why you want this.  You want to disable navigation completely or do you want to use the cursor keys for something else?  Don't forget about the other keystrokes that change the selected tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to extend TabControl, just subscribe to its KeyDown event and handle it.

```
tabControl1.KeyDown+=new KeyEventHandler(tabControl1_KeyDown);
```

---

```
private void tabControl1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

tabControl1 doesn't change pages. KeyUp of the form and tabControl1 fires normally.

Comment: It works fine but **it also prevents event handling in child components** because their parent component is handled first. So, if you need to handle an event in a child (e.g. arrow navigation in DataGridView), you need to fire a new event, the child has to subscribe to this event and handle it. Another option is additional condition, e.g. `((Control)sender).Focused && (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)` but this can work only if all child components are handling the event.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is that you simply grab those keys at the `Form` level and set the `Handled` property to `true` (by returning `true`) so that the control won't get the key press.

Add this method to your `Form`:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Left || keyData == Keys.Right)
    {
        // do what you need to do and the
        // return true will stop processing
        return true;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for this.

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) 
{
    //your logic
    e.SuppressKeyPress();
}
```

[this is where I got it from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749674/how-to-intercept-the-tab-key-press-to-prevent-standard-focus-change-in-c-sharp)