# Windows Forms: set Tab as shortcut

Tags: c#, winforms

There is no reaction on `Tab` shortcut in my app:

```
public class SomeWindow : Form {

    // ...

    private void someWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(SomeWindow_KeyDown);

    }

    void SomeWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {

        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.B) {
            // some actions
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) {
            // no reaction
        }
    }
}
```

I learned that `Tab` and direction keys are required some overrides, but all examples that I saw was related to textboxes. Any solutions for Tas as shortcut?

Comment: I just tried your code. When pressing `Tab` that code triggers. Where's the problem?

Comment: @Erik Kralj, I don`t have `Tab OK` output in console from `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TabOK");} else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("A Ok"); }`. `A Ok` is no problem.

Comment: Hint: don't use `Tab` as shortcut. Bad idea. This makes world worse. Users will hate you.

Comment: @Sinatr, even if it's required to switch between textboxes? (I need tab will make active textbox B only when caret in textbox A).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to intercept the TAB key press to prevent standard focus change in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749674/how-to-intercept-the-tab-key-press-to-prevent-standard-focus-change-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Using `Tab` for changing focus between controls is ok (it's not if you want to use `Tab` to always set focus to just one control). Why are you disabling `B`? If `A` has focus and `B` is enabled, then pressing `Tab` will occasionally set focus to `B`. You should take care about [tab order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19278278/1997232) rather than handling `Tab` key presses manually.

Comment: @Sinatr, there are many controls in my window. There are no reason to always keep enabled tabstop for B.

Comment: *"keep enabled tabstop for B"* - what does this means? Do you want control to get focus - then don't set [`TabStop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop(v=vs.110).aspx) to `false`. I repeat: normally you don't need manually process `Tab` key presses, instead, take care about tab order (by setting `TabIndex` of controls) and then `Tab` key will do the job. Btw, there is `Shift`+`Tab` to go back. If you have unusual scenario where you may have to do something with `Tab` (e.g. attempt to make a game in winforms) - then so far you didn't explain it.

Comment: **TabStop** is a control's (button, textbox etx.) property, when it is `false` it's impossible to focus on respective control by Tab key. I mean that I think what it's better to set B textbox **tabstop** property to `false` because the controls number is too big. O'K, got it! Thank you for the advice.